# Why does ssh public key authentication stop working when I am tunneling ssh commands through a machine?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

On Computer A, I have a public and private key for my github account. When I use this machine directly, using a connected keyboard and display, I can do all the git remote repo commands, like git pull and git push, as well as ssh -vv git@github.com. All this works and uses the proper ssh keypair.

But if I log into Computer A from Computer B, and then try the same stuff as above, I can't seem to get the same ssh keys to work with GitHub's servers. There is absolutely no difference here, except that I am controlling Computer A via an ssh connection, rather than directly via the computer's keyboard.

What's going on here exactly, and how can I learn more about it?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it's possible that you've got [agent forwarding](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html) enabled on your connection from Computer B which results in keys on **B** overriding keys on **A**.

Github has [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding) describing how you can use `ssh -T` on their servers to check your connection. Use `ssh -T -vvv` to see what's going on and which keys are being pulled.